# Specifying node version for a certain test

Tags: node.js, bash, mocha.js, travis-ci

Is it possible to specify in package.json's `test` to run a certain test if the node version is greater that x? Currently, I'm using Travis with mocha and my script looks like the following:

```
if [node --version > '0.10'] then mocha --harmony ./tests/koa/*.js else mocha ./tests/*.js
```

I've found out that it seems possible to use if statements from [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/), but using the above just gives me an error: `--version was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Did you just create a file named `0.10]`?

Comment: Try: `if [[ $(node --version) > '0.10' ]]; then mocha --harmony ./tests/koa/*.js else mocha ./tests/*.js; fi`. Observe the spaces around `[[`, `>` and `]]`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I was trying to compare the version so the logic that I would like is:
if (node version is greater than .10) then (run test x) else (run test y)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf awesome it worked on Travis!  (I think) https://travis-ci.org/iwatakeshi/gengojs But it doesn't seem to work on git-bash for windows.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Correction: Actually, it just exited with 0 but didn't run any tests.

Answer (score 2):

So, it wasn't quite what I wanted to do but I ended up messing with the .travis.yaml file and created a script. First I created a new script in package.json like the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --harmony ./tests/koa/*.js && mocha ./tests/*.js",
    "0.10": "mocha ./tests/*.js"
}
```

then I edited the .yaml file to the following:

```
language: node_js

node_js:
  - 0.12
  - 0.11
  - 0.10
  - iojs

script:
  nv=$(node -v);
  if [[ $nv != v0.10.36 ]] ; then
    npm test;
  else
    npm run 0.10;
  fi
```

and there you have a way to use your tests in different node version. This is quite handy when you want to use `--harmony` even if you want to support v0.10, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Edit: credits to @gniourf_gniourf for given me the right direction.